# htaccess redirect from one domain to another Authorization not working in header

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

We have created webservice in codeigniter for android application.

Now are moving our domain. We can not give quick update for the users that are using current domain webservices.

So trying to use htaccess rules in my old domain.

Here is the rules that i have added.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

This is working and redirecting when we open our admin in browser.
But the issue is, in android app's web services we are authenticating users.
So there is Authorization set in all services in the header. And when we redirect web services request using above rules, we are unable to get headers data in the new domain.

```
$header = getallheaders();

$header['Authorization'] //we are not getting this one
```

I am not getting how to pass headers data when we redirect from one domain to another.